# Weird encoding issue with Axios and the reddit API json

Tags: json, axios, encoding, reddit, astrojs

I'm learning [astro.build](https://astro.build) by creating a Reddit browser, but I'm struggling with some encoding issues on the posts data... As you can see from the image attached the rendering in the dev tools works fine, while the page is not showing the correct emoji (or any other utf-8 char).

I tried to play with different encodings, but without success. And the fact that the response preview pane in both firefox and chrome makes me more confused...

This is my axios request

```
 const response: AxiosResponse = await axios.get(`${REDDIT_BASE_URL}/r/${subreddit}/.json`, {
      params: searchParams,
      responseType: 'json',
      responseEncoding: 'utf8',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
    });
```

and this is my astro page `<head>`

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta content="index,follow" name="robots"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.svg" />
        <meta name="generator" content={Astro.generator} />
        <title>{title} - {name}</title>
    </head>
```

What can be wrong?

[image: difference in rendering]

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `''.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `'ðŸ˜Š'` and vice versa: `'ðŸ˜Š'.encode( 'cp1252').decode( 'utf-8')` -> `''`. **Note**. Please [*do not* use (sole) images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code. Post a hexadecimal dump in case of (partially) binary content.

Comment: just added the image because it was showing different renderings for the same output, but thanks